# How to return the error from the gouroutine inside a loop early?

Tags: go, error-handling, concurrency, channel, goroutine

I have a goroutine inside a loop and the way I am handling the error is that I add it to a channel and after all the goroutines are finished, I check if there was an error and I return accordingly.

The issue with this is that I want to return an error as soon as I get it so that I don't spend time waiting for all the goroutines to finish as it would be inefficient.

I tried adding the `select` statement but it doesn't work and I can't add the `select` statement inside the goroutines since I want to exit the for loop and the `try` function too.

How can I do this?

Here is the code:

```
package main

import (
    "sync"
    "runtime"
    "fmt"
    "errors"
)

func try() (bool, error) {
    wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)

    s := []int{0,1,2,3,4,5}
    ec := make(chan error)
    
    for i, val := range s {
    /*
        select {
             case err, ok := <-ec:
        if ok {
            println("error 1", err.Error())
            return false, err
        }
            default:
            }
    */
        wg.Add(1)
        i := i
        val := val
        go func() {
            err := func(i int, val int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) error {
                defer wg.Done()
                
                if i == 3 {
                    return errors.New("one error")
                } else {
                    return nil
                }
                
            }(i, val, wg)
            if err != nil {
                ec <- err
                return
            }
        }()
    }
    wg.Wait()
    
    select {
    case err, ok := <-ec:
        if ok {
            println("error 2", err.Error())
            return false, err
        }
    default:
    }
    
    return true, nil
}

func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())
    b, e := try()
    if e != nil {
        fmt.Println(e.Error(), b)
    } 
    
}
```

[This is the go playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/sAw6BrDsjEO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `wg.Wait()` before your `select` statement, you are effectively waiting for all goroutines to return.

> The issue with this is that I want to return an error as soon as I get it

I assume that with this you mean stopping running goroutines as soon as any one of them returns an error.

In this case, you could use `context.Context` to manage cancellation, but even better is an [`errgroup.Group`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sync/errgroup), which nicely combines  context functionality and synchronization:

> Package errgroup provides synchronization, error propagation, and Context cancelation for groups of goroutines working on subtasks of a common task.

In particular [`Group.Go`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sync/errgroup#Group.Go):

> The first call to return a non-nil error cancels the group; its error will be returned by Wait.

```
import (
    "sync"
    "runtime"
    "fmt"
    "errors"
    "golang.org/x/sync/errgroup"
)

func try() (bool, error) {
    errg := new(errgroup.Group)

    s := []int{0,1,2,3,4,5}
    
    for i, val := range s {       
        i := i
        val := val

        errg.Go(func() error {
            return func(i int, val int) error {
                if i == 3 {
                    return errors.New("one error")
                } else {
                    return nil
                }
            }(i, val)
        })
    }
    
    if err := errg.Wait(); err != nil {
        // handle error
    }
    
    return true, nil
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/lSIIFJqXf0W

Answer (score 1):

I have found [tomb](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/tomb.v2?utm_source=godoc) to be useful for this. Below is a stripped-down non-working example that shows the gist, without handling things like variable encapsulation in the loop. It should give you the idea, but I'm happy to clarify on any points.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/tomb.v2"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    ts := tomb.Tomb{}
    s := []int{0,1,2,3,4,5}

    for i, v := range s {
        ts.Go(func() error {
            // do some work here or return an error, make sure to watch the dying chan, if it closes, 
            //then one of the other go-routines failed.
            select {
            case <- ts.Dying():
                return nil
            case err := <- waitingForWork():
                if err != nil {
                    return err
                }
                return nil
            }
        })
    }

    // If an error appears here, one of the go-routines must have failed
    err := ts.Wait()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```